# Python : Convert a one dimension list to a 2 dimension one without numpy

Tags: python, list, dimension

So, i want to convert a one dim list into a 2 dim one :
The first list have a lenght of n² . The second one must be n*n. How to do that without numpy ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `n² == n*n` you know

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: yeah of course I know that n² = n*n, It was mathematically speaking, to let people know the dimension

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to organize a flat list into a "square" nested list depending on the counting order. Here the most natural example:

```
flat_list = list(range(16))

dim = int(len(flat_list)**.5)

square_list = [flat_list[dim*i: dim*(i+1)] for i in range(dim)]

print(square_list)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Remark: the list is assumed to have `n**2` elements as mentioned in the question otherwise add a conditional check with a proper exception handler

Comment: edit: flat_list -> dim -> "square" list